# sympy set range of implicit plot (entity cut off)

Tags: python, plot, range, sympy

I don't manage to set the range so that the circle isn't cut off. I hope someone can help me.

**Edited code:**

I want to mirror the point 'V' at the line g.

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot
from sympy.plotting import plot_implicit
from sympy.geometry import Circle
from sympy import solve
import numpy as np   

x, y = symbols(['x', 'y'])
g = 4*x-3*y+1
V = np.array([5,2])
n = np.array([4, -3])
abs_n = np.linalg.norm(n)
hnf_g = abs(g/abs_n)
mirrored_V = V - 2*hnf_g.evalf(subs={x:V[0], y:V[1]}) * n/abs_n
y_g = solve(g,y)

p = plot(y_g[0], show=False, xlim=(-10,10), ylim=(-10,10))
p.extend(plot_implicit(Circle(V,1).equation(), var_start_end_x=(x,-10,10), var_start_end_y=(y,-10,10)))
p.extend(plot_implicit(Circle(mirrored_V,1).equation(), var_start_end_x=(x,-10,10), var_start_end_y=(y,-10,10)))
p.show()
```

New result:

[image: New result]

Old:

This is the result for the whole plot:
[image: whole plot]

If I only have a look at the implicit plot:
[image: only implicit plot with the circle]

Comment: Can you provide more of your code for context? I want to run your code myself to verify your issue

Comment: @YakovDan thank you for your comment. I added more code and context to my question. You should get the same result if you copy and run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs for [`plot_implicit`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit) this can be accomplished this by setting the range as shown in the third example, copied below.

```
p2 = plot_implicit(Eq(x**2 + y**2, 3), (x, -3, 3), (y, -3, 3))
```

But this requires an `Eq` object, which unfortunately either can't be constructed from a `Circle` for these purposes - possibly as the result of a bug which passes a `bool` instead of a `bool` tuple - or I am missing something. If it is the former then

```
Eq(Circle(Point(0,0),1).equation())
```

is insufficient, and you must construct the circle equation explicitly, i.e.

```
Eq((x - 5)**2 + (y - 2)**2 - 1, 1)
```

---

#### Complete Example

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot
from sympy.plotting import plot_implicit
from sympy.geometry import Circle
from sympy import solve
import numpy as np   

x, y = symbols(['x', 'y'])
g = 4*x-3*y+1
V = np.array([5,2])
n = np.array([4, -3])
abs_n = np.linalg.norm(n)
hnf_g = abs(g/abs_n)
mirrored_V = V - 2*hnf_g.evalf(subs={x:V[0], y:V[1]}) * n/abs_n
y_g = solve(g,y)

p = plot(y_g[0], show=False, xlim=(-10,10), ylim=(-10,10))
p.extend(plot_implicit(Eq((x - V[0])**2 + (y - V[1])**2, 1), 
                       (x,-10,10), (y,-10,10), show=False))
p.extend(plot_implicit(Eq((x - mirrored_V[0])**2 + (y - mirrored_V[1])**2, 1), 
                       (x,-10,10), (y,-10,10), show=False))
p.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations and a possible solution!